# Controlling ActionScript 3 with dynamically loaded text file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, double-click

I am successfully able to load an external text file into my Flash movie using AS3. The loaded text file has links which are going to external pdfs. This is working fine, too. Problem is, now I need to call a function inside the Flash file from the links instead of opening the external pdfs. These are DoubleClick ads, in case anyone is familiar.

Here is the AS around a button in the current Flash movie. I have to somehow call a similar function from the text file.

```
theBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag;
    if(click_url) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to display the pdfs inside the flash file?

Comment: No, Daniel, I am not.

Comment: could you expand on what you mean by `now I need to call a function inside the Flash file from the links instead of opening the external pdfs`?

Comment: What is the problem? You open links the same you did with the PDF files. How did you extract the URL of the PDFs in first place. When you extract "**http..../test.pdf**" from text file why cant you also extract "**http..../somead.html**"?

Comment: So, you have an AS file to download and execute? If you'd manage to do that, you are in the world of pain, if someone would use your app to execute malicious code. This should not be possible. You can read parameters out of a text file, but you should never read executable code from there.

Comment: The problem is that DoubleClick ads require the URLs for all links to be pulled from Flash variables programmed in the HTML of the page the .swf file is located in. Hence the code above'var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag;'. The external text file links need to call the variable 'clickTag2' and 'clickTag3', etc, to get their values.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the `this[string]` syntax against `root.loaderInfo.parameters`. Then, if your loaded text file says there should be a `clickTag2` variable, available via string `variableName`, you use that in your function like this:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters[variableName];
    // here you are, now your function queries dynamic vars
    if(click_url) {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
    }
}
```